# GitHub Pages does not update when the branch is updated from within GH Actions

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages

I have a repo with branch `autogen-docs`, and a folder `docs` in it. GitHub Pages is correctly targeting that branch & folder and it builds the docs website based on the files in the folder. If I manually push an update to this branch, the documentation updates correctly.

[image]

But I want the website to update automatically as part of CI/CD. Hence, in my CI/CD in GitHub Actions, I run the following job, which basically recreates the `autogen-docs` branch with the new docs and force-pushes it back to origin:

```
  update-docs:
    name : Update docs
    runs-on: [ docker-runner ]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - uses: ./.github/actions/setup-env
        with:
          environment: dev

      - name: Generate docs
        run: |
          echo ${{ github.ref }}
          git config user.name github-actions
          git config user.email github-actions@github.com

          rm -rf ./docs 
          poetry run python ./my_pkg/auto_docs/generate_docs.py

          git branch -D autogen-docs &>/dev/null || true
          git checkout -b autogen-docs
          git add -A docs
          git commit -m "docs update"
          git push -f origin autogen-docs
```

The job runs successfully and I can see in GitHub that the branch has been updated with the newly generated files.

[image]

However, the page never updates - it seems like the process that rebuilds the website based on the source never triggers. Even if I unpublish and re-publish the site though, it does not rebuild. However, when I push a commit manually from my local machine, the site rebuilds and updates correctly.

How can I make this work as part of the CI/CD?

Comment: That's deliberate, per e.g. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#using-the-github_token-in-a-workflow events triggered with the default token won't create new workflow runs.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I managed to solve this by manually triggering the GH pages update at the end of the job.

```
          curl -L \
            -X POST \
            -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
            -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.<GH-TOKEN> }}" \
            -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
            https://api.github.my-org.com/repos/my-org/my-repo/pages/builds
```

https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/pages/pages?apiVersion=2022-11-28#request-a-github-pages-build

And @jonrsharpe's answer above seems to explain why this wasn't triggering on its own in the first place.